# Cant launch Gitblit GO

Tags: git, gitblit

I have troubles trying to setup Gitblit GO.

I am following [this documentation.](http://gitblit.com/setup_go.html)

On step 3 I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jgit/erro
rs/ConfigInvalidException
        at com.gitblit.authority.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.ConfigInval
idException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

If i just skip step 3 I got this error on step 4:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kohsuke/args4j/Cm
dLineException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.moxie.MxLauncher.main(MxLauncher.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineException

        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

What should I do to make it work?

Additional data:
JRE version - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
GitBlit folder - C:\GitServerPractice\GitBlit
GitBlit properties - default, i tried to change basic properties, without success anyway
Platform - Windows 7 Ultimate (I'm testing git server implementations on work station)

Answer (score 2):

You can only start GitBlit if you are in the installation directory. In your case it should be C:\GitServerPractice\GitBlit

```
    cd /d C:\GitServerPractice\GitBlit && java -jar gitblit.jar --baseFolder data
```

See https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/issues/930

Comment: I it is not looks like my issue. And i cant really reproduce my issue to validate this solution cause i gave up on gitblit long time ago. But i am upvoting this anyway in case it will help someone.

Comment: You can also comment to realted issue if you want to: https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/issues/1071. Gitblit github is stale and this issue remains innoticed for months.